# 'User' object has no attribute 'student_set'

Tags: django

```
class BasicInfo(models.Model):
  username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=250)
  abstratct=True

class Student(Basicinfo):
   #Student class definition
```

When I query :

```
user=user.objects.get(user="name")
student=Student.objects.get(username=user)
```

But :

```
user.student_set.all() gives error
```

> 'User' object has no attribute 'student_set'??

Comment: set only comes if you are using ForeignKey or ManyToManyField

Answer (score 1):

Just add related_name to student model to access:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name